# What does "steps" in this sentence mean?

Tags: word-meaning

While I was reading my book I saw a sentence and I don't know completely
meaning of it because "steps" word in the sentence keeps me from understanding the sentence completely.

Sentence: He went down the **steps** into the tunnel.

What kind of meaning does this word make to the sentence ?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try looking it up in the dictionary? If so, what confused you? There's not really anything special going on in this sentence. It's the first definition if you look it up on m-w.com.

Comment: I know exactly what step and steps mean but I don't know the meaning of it in the  sentence above that I've given.

Comment: See the answer below by Michael Harvey, but basically "steps", while they are the individual elements that make up a **stair case**, can also be used to refer to the stair case itself. If the person goes *down* the steps, they are going down in elevation, from the top step to the bottom one. Presumably there's a tunnel at the bottom of the stair case that the person walked into once he got to the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a picture of some steps

[image]

and one from a **dictionary**! (Cambridge)

[image]

[Step (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/step)